# Find glade gtk3 widget by unique id

Tags: c, widget, gtk3, glade

In glade I can give a unique id to each widget, however in the c-code, I have no idea how I can make use of these id's.

The method "gtk_widget_get_name" seems to return something else. At least currently I only get the typenames from it, e.g. "GtkGrid", "GtkComboBoxText", "GtkStatusbar" ... thats probably the default if I did not set a different name in the c-code.

So how can I read the id of a gtkwidget, which I typed into glade ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Glade ID is used with [`gtk_builder_get_object()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-get-object) to retrieve an object or widget by its ID from a Glade file.

The [`name`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget--name) property which `gtk_widget_get_name()` retrieves, fulfills a different function: referring to your widget from a CSS file. It's for widgets only, not objects, and moreover there's nothing that forces it to be unique.

Comment: Thank's alot, exactly the method I was looking for!

Comment: I just asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812379/how-can-i-read-out-the-glade-id-of-a-gtk3-object). Maybe you as well know the answer for this one.